# Assistance with unsecure image on wp site (mixed content)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have recently installed a SSL certificate and have installed and activated the plugin from my site called "Really Simple SSL".

This fixed most of my links on the site but I cannot fix this for the main background image.

I have gone through my theme files to try and find the PHP and CSS that points to the jquery javascipt file but do not understand where it is coming from.

I don't really understand the code in the javascript files to edit them and stop this.

I commented out some of the PHP that links to bodybg but it has not helped.

Can you help me?

It says the initiator is the js file.

I hope what i wrote makes sense. Hopefully this image will give a better understanding:

[image: WP site help, SSL site]

Comment: Use `$(document).ready()` when initialising plugins.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is this related to this issue or something else with my theme files?

Comment: are both urls in general settings set to use https?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but it looks like It's in your CSS, line 44ish of this CSS file https://tfpcservices.net/wp-content/themes/toommorel-lite/style.css?ver=5c4b921636f9c0c7831371bff79f8834 - change `http://tfpcservices.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/body3.png`
to 
`https://tfpcservices.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/body3.png`

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Yes the WP settings are correct. Also I have a child theme which should overide the settings from the original one

Comment: Is there actually any risk if this happens? Can malicious activity happen from an insecure image?